# slf4j version mismatch and multiple binding with kotlin-main-kts

Tags: maven, slf4j

I'm working on a Quarkus project with maven, that has multiple modules and includes the kotlin-main-kts lib.
Here's information about my bug:

- I have multiple slf4j bindings error/warning
- I also have versions mismatch that prevents me to start the project
- Locally, I can run the project but not when I package it and try to run with docker
- The message is `The requested version 2.0.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]`
- In the end, it crashed with another message : `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.slf4j.helpers.FormattingTuple org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'`
- According to the stacktrace below, there are two bindings:

  - org.jboss.slf4j.slf4j-jboss-logmanager-2.0.0.Final.jar
  - org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-main-kts-1.9.10.jar

Please note that the `slf4j-jboss-logmanager` is a peer dependency of Quarkus which is imported in the main pom.xml, and `kotlin-main-kts` is a direct dependency which is imported in a project's submodule dependency.

What's weird, is that if I show the dependency tree (`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=*slf4j*`), slf4j won't be shown as a kotlin-main-kts dependency whereas it is for jboss-logmanager:

```
[INFO] com.my.package:produit:jar:1.0.12-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.quarkus:quarkus-core:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logmanager:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] \- io.mockk:mockk-jvm:jar:1.13.4:test
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
```

So I tried a lot of things, like dependencyManagement, exclusions, but it doesn't seem to work, however it's the first time I do this, so maybe I did something wrong.
I think it may be related on [the way kotlin-main-kts includes the jar](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53283)

**The stacktrace**

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/jboss/lib/main/org.jboss.slf4j.slf4j-jboss-logmanager-2.0.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/jboss/lib/main/org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-main-kts-1.9.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: The requested version 2.0.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
The DelayedHandler was closed before any children handlers were configured. Messages will be written to stderr.
2023-11-03 09:42:26,816 DEBUG [org.jboss.logging] (main) Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.JBossLogManagerProvider

2023-11-03 09:42:28,808 DEBUG [io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory] (main) Using SLF4J as the default logging framework

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:61)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.slf4j.helpers.FormattingTuple org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.debug(LocationAwareSlf4JLogger.java:108)
    at io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap.<clinit>(InternalThreadLocalMap.java:100)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocal.<init>(FastThreadLocal.java:128)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.runtime.VertxCurrentContextFactory$VertxCurrentContext.<init>(VertxCurrentContextFactory.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.runtime.VertxCurrentContextFactory.create(VertxCurrentContextFactory.java:21)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.<init>(ArcContainerImpl.java:194)
    at io.quarkus.arc.Arc.initialize(Arc.java:39)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.initContainer(ArcRecorder.java:47)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. In fact, the conflict was between `netty-common` and `kotlin-main-kts` (if we look at the stacktrace, there's a `at io.netty.util.internal.logging.LocationAwareSlf4JLogger`).

The reason of this is that kotlin-main-kts uses a weird way to add the slf4j dependency, and I can't explain why, but netty relies on this one instead of the one which is included by maven in the jar (and included with the right version 2.0.6).

What I did: I deleted the dependency to kotlin-main-kts and instead, added the 3 dependencies of kotlin-main-kts (kotlin-stdlib, kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable, kotlin-reflect), which is ok in my case.
It's hacky, but it's the only way I found to make it work.